# Jquery Validation OnBlur of textbox

Tags: jquery

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function checkdata() {

        $("#TextBoxesGroup :input").each(function () {
            if (!$(this).val()) {
                alert(this.val()+":Dis");
                $("#addButton").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }
            else {
                alert(this.val() + ":Ena");
                $("#addButton").removeAttr("disabled");
            }
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#addButton").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $("#TextBoxesGroup :input").each(function () {
            $(this).blur(function () {
                checkdata();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Html

```
<div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
    <div style="float: left; width: 625px;">
        <div>
        <input type="text" name="answer" class="ahsan" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;">
</div>
<div>
    <input type="button" value="Add New Row" class="qa-adbtn" id='addButton' />
</div>
```

Now the thing i want to do is that if user enter something in textbox(ahsan) .then add button enabled and if there is nothing in textbox onblur then add button automatically goes disabled

Answer (score 5):

this works

```
    function checkdata() {
var ok = true;
        $("#TextBoxesGroup :input").each(function () {

            if (!$(this).val()) {             
               ok = false;
               return;
            }

        });
if (ok) $("#addButton").removeAttr("disabled");
else   $("#addButton").attr("disabled", "disabled");

    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#addButton").attr("disabled", "disabled");

            $("#TextBoxesGroup :input").blur(function () {
                checkdata();
            });

    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
    <div style="float: left; width: 625px;">
        <div>
        <input type="text" name="answer" class="ahsan" />
 <input type="text" name="answer" class="ahsan" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;">
</div>
<div>
    <input type="button" value="Add New Row" class="qa-adbtn" id='addButton' />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @user1145150 then why don't you accept the solution.It will help for others.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
function checkdata() {
    $("#TextBoxesGroup :input").each(function() {
        if($(this).val().trim().length < 1) {
            alert($(this).val() + ":Dis");
            $("#addButton").attr("disabled", true);
        }
        else {
            alert($(this).val() + ":Ena");
            $("#addButton").attr("disabled", false);
        }
    });
}

$(function () {
    $("#addButton").attr("disabled", true);
        $("#TextBoxesGroup input").blur(function () {
        checkdata();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Each loop is not required as blur function is bind to each text box.

Try this

```
    $("#addButton").attr("disabled", true);
    $("#TextBoxesGroup input").blur(function () {
    if($(this).val()== ""  ) {
        $("#addButton").attr("disabled", true);
    }
    else {
        $("#addButton").attr("disabled", false);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the following fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/TChNC/

Use keypress event and if length of txtbox is greater dan enable your button

Edit:

In Fiddle i have kept the button as disabled bydefault you can make appropriate changes as per your need..